# How to move from one record to another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created an `onclick` function which should run an SQL statement, select URLs from the statement and opens the Excel files sequentially from the URL.

It works but if the query returns 3 results then it opens the same excel file 3 times.

Instead of opening one file after the other it opens the same file.

This is what I have:

```
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Dim appexcel As Object
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    strSQL = "SELECT * from [PROCESSED_CONTRACTS_PRINTALL]"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    urlval = rs!url
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
    Set appexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appexcel.workbooks.Open urlval
    appexcel.Visible = True
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Any help please? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, note that urlval is now inside the loop and Excel is outside the loop.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim appexcel As Object
Set db = CurrentDb()
strSQL = "SELECT * from [PROCESSED_CONTRACTS_PRINTALL]"
Set appexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appexcel.Visible = True
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
  urlval = rs!url
  appexcel.workbooks.Open urlval
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```